# Integrate Spring with Log4j2

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, log4j2

I would like to Spring use Log4j2 for logging because sometimes i would like to get debug level. I've read tons of related topics and examples but noithing is working.. I managed to configure log4j2 and log from my own classes but not from spring.
What i got:
Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
    <!-- SERVLT API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- APACHE TILES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- APACHE FILEUPLOAD -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring ORM support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LOGGING -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logger.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${logger.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>${logger.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${logger.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- POSTGRE DRIVER -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1207.jre7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JACKSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

log4j.xml: (edit: file name is log4j2.xml -sorry for mistake)

```
<Configuration status="debug">
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="systemLog" fileName="C:\\test\logs\system.log" includeLocation="true"
                filePattern="C:\\test\logs\system-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} - %-5level [%t] %C %M %m%n" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="15 MB"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    <Async name="systemAsyncAppender" includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="systemLog" />
    </Async>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.springframework.web" level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="systemAsyncAppender" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug" includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="systemAsyncAppender" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

If there is something relevalt that i didnt told - tell me

I will be realy greatfull for helping me out with this

Comment: I dont see any log4j2 dependency in your pom.xml file.

Comment: 1. I believe config file for Log4J 2 is log4j2.xml  2. You do not need to have Log4J2 to get DEBUG level.  Almost any SLF4j binding can do it

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-*` are actually artifcats of log4j2

Comment: @Adrian Shum - you are right and i made a mistake in post. The file is log4j2.xml and i know it is lading properly. Could you link to some example of configuring SLF4j? I'm not really atached to log4j2 so i am open to other logging frameworks.

Comment: @TomaszSkaba Did you find a solution? I'm stucked with the same problem. I've tried to use commons-logging with jcl bridge, or slf4j with its bridge, but spring still doesn't log. Despite this, in both configuration I've managed to make mine logs within the application, and hibernate logs working properly.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is using Spring 5 and coming to this post, please note, as stated in the [initial Spring 5 documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/overview.html#overview-logging) (or more briefly explained in the [current version](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#spring-jcl)):

- There is no need for external bridges like JCL-over-SLF4J anymore, and correspondingly no need for a manual exclude of the standard Commons Logging jar from spring-core dependencies.
- Simply put Log4j 2.x or SLF4J on your classpath, without any extra bridge jars, or rely on default logging through JUL (with a customizable JUL setup).

That is, for `Log4j 2`, add its dependency to your `pom.xml` as follows :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```

- As of Spring 5, drop any references to external Commons Logging bridges and also any manual exclude of the standard Commons Logging jar from your existing spring-core dependency setup. Your Log4j or SLF4J or JUL setup will keep working without changes. Note that you may still need a commons-logging exclude for other libraries (e.g. Apache HttpClient, Castor, HtmlUnit) in order to pick up Spring’s JCL bridge instead.

As a reminder of how to use Log4j2 :

#### In your java code

As per the [Apache Log4j 2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html):

```java
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
     
    public class HelloWorld {
        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            logger.info("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
```

#### Configuration file in `/src/main/resources`

You will need a `log4j2` configuration file, either in `xml`, `json` or `yaml` format.

Details and example in [Log4j 2 reference documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Log4j Configuration -->
<bean id="log4jInitializer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod">
        <value>org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging</value>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>${path.to.log4j.file}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Add this in your spring context file

Comment: I think this is the way when you are configuring log4j not log4j2. I get error : ERROR DOM element is - not a <log4j:configuration> element.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Spring uses commons logging so you need the commons logging jar and the log4j-jcl jar.

Comment: No, the shim provided by slf4j which simulates commons logging will do.

Comment: That will route commons logging into slf4j and then into log4j.  It is better to use commons logging and use log4j's bridge.